# CocoaPods not working in macOS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, cocoapods, macos-high-sierra

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra CocoaPods is not working. While it is tempting to move away from CocoaPods, it's unfortunately not in scope right now. The error message is below.

```
zsh: /Users/****/.gems/bin/pod: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin: no such file or directory
```

I realize that the error stems from Ruby being upgraded but what is the easies fix? Trying to make CocoaPods use the new ruby version yields other errors.

Edit: For now i installed `Ruby 2.0` with `rvm install 2.0.0` and `rvm use 2.0.0` and then reinstalled CocoaPods `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Did you update the Command Line Tools?

Comment: @matt Yes, `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app` and `sudo xcode-select --install` and followed the GUI from there.

Comment: I was thinking of the ones here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ I often find external tools don't work until I install those.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

According to https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6778 reinstalling CocoaPods should solve this issue:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: A simple "brew reinstall cocoapods" worked (as it runs this exact command for you). Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Although this works, it should definitely be a CocoaPods issue, since it is unable to locate the updated Ruby version. Probably reinstalling it just checks for the installation again and therefore "fixes" it.

Comment: gem install cocoapods - throws no implicit conversion of nil to string error but "brew reinstall cocoapods" did the job. thanks @Markus

Comment: gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods helps me

Comment: Since i updated to 10.13 OS, Provided `sudo gem install cocoapods` **again** & it's worked.

Comment: I hit this on Mojave on omitted `sudo`, so just `gem install cocoapods` and it worked, thanks

Comment: Works for macOS Catalina (v10.15), as well.

Comment: Works for macOS Catalina too.

Answer (score 120):

After upgrading to macOS High Sierra, get it fixed with following commands:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

once it will be finished then write below command:

```
pod install
```

This solution has worked for me...!!!

Comment: I got "ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem" when running the first command, but running the second still made "pod install" work. Thanks.

Comment: Despite the "warning", I'm going to say thanks here anyway.  This was the only thing that worked for me.  Simply reinstalling cocoapods (several times) made no difference until I did both of these steps.  So - thanks!

Comment: I had to run the ruby update through the following command:
`sudo gem update -n /usr/local/bin --system`

Comment: Worked for me (cocoapods 1.5.3).

Comment: After literally trying hundreds of other proposed solutions and spending hours and hours this one finally worked. I can now safely say I love you just as much as I hate the Apple/Mac dev environment! Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

I got this error while installing the CocoaPods

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

And I used this statement. It worked!

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: This is the only solution that seemed to work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me, although I had to do

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 11):

This solved my problem:

```
$ brew install ruby
$ gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: Please give a short explanation of what the posted code does so people that are new to this technology have a change to understand and re-use your answer :-)

Comment: People new to cocoapods should know how to read like the others.

Comment: @MathieuVIALES, the "brew install ruby" assumes you already have Homebrew packager (https://brew.sh). 

That command then installs (or probably technically re-installs ruby since you actually need ruby to install Homebrew itself).  

The next line "gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods" reinstalls the CocoaPod program (more at https://cocoapods.org).

Answer (score 9):

Simply run below command:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 6):

So I ran into this problem as well after having updated to High Sierra, and it seems like there's been some changes to a location of file that the ruby framework was accessing.

You can solve it using the,

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and then update pods as well with for safe measures

```
pod repo update
```

and finally

```
pod install
```

to make the pod file work again.

Hope this helps out :)

Answer (score 6):

Try using

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Before

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Cocoapods install process:

1. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
   (if you have any problem cocoapds, please update gem file)
2. `sudo gem update --system`
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
which pod
```

It still showed it in the path, so I deleted that.  Made sure it still didn't show up.

Then

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Finally ! Deleting old pod executable before installing cocoapods worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Go to Terminal...

step 1). sudo gem install cocoapods

after completion of install cocoa pods then

step 2).   pod repo update

Completed

Answer (score 4):

MacOS High Sierra uses ruby 2.3 by default. After upgrading to it, some old ruby gems might not function properly. This problem occurs to me when I ran the bundle command (bundler is a ruby gem; it has a utility called bundle).

So, to clarify, any old ruby gems (cocoapods, bundler, etc) that are trying to access ruby 2.0 will fail.

The solution is to reinstall those old gems in a directory where you have permissions to write.

For cocoapods,

`sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin`

will do the trick.

You can optionally upgrade your gem system if you like `before` the install:

`sudo gem update --system`

This may prompt to you that the upgrading has failed. But actually, if you type:

`gem --version`

You can see that the upgrading has been successful.

For bundler or other gems, try to do the same:

`sudo gem install gem-to-install(for example, bundler) -n /usr/local/bin`

About the `-n` option. Don't miss that. You can check the gem documentation if you want.

So, the solution is all about `reinstalling the old gem` to a proper directory.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error after installing `High Sierra`.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

I used the following statement identified by Danh Huynh (see above) and It worked!

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46520248), isn't it?

Comment: this fixed it for me

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 2):

### Sudo-less .zhs-friendly solution

Modern macOS discourages using `sudo` and shifts from bash to zsh, so this answer may be useful if you are not going to fight with the fashion.

1. Insure that `.zshenv` exists by `touch ~/.zshenv` command. Configure the RubyGems environment by adding following lines:

   ```
   export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
   export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Don't forget to relaunch Terminal.
2. Run `gem install cocoapods`.

Comment: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/shubhamojha/.local/share/gem/specs

Answer (score 1):

While I'm doing the same I got another error saying that

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

Then I did this and worked fine.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a same issue, resolution:

1. Reinstall ruby

   `brew install ruby`
2. Reinstall Cocoa Pods

   `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when upgraded to Mac OSX High Sierra.

Fix is simply installing Cocoapods (again):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

Running this on terminal worked for me:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

After using the below command on the terminal, I am able to install cocoa pods in my project.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue also but fixed it in less dramatical way as various re-installation / updating. Just updated PATH environment variable to point out my existing (2.6.0) ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Catalina.

1. I updated ruby install by first installing brew and ruby using these directions.
   https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina (but only ruby, not rails, etc.)
2. Then I reinstalled cocoapods using the instructions above.

   sudo gem install cocoapods

Then after all that I still received the error above.
Then I typed 'zsh' to spawn a new shell and pull in configuration settings in the ~/.zshrc file.
After this 'pod update' command worked again.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
    curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
    sudo update gems
    rvm install 2.6.0
    sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I used homebrew to install cocoapods on High Sierra (macOS 10.13.6) it works for me

brew install cocoapods

after this flutter doctor shows no errors.

I am able to deploy my Flutter app to IOS XS Max

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30514920)

Answer (score -1):

```
If cannot install new version cocoapods, example below:
1. Please remove Command line tools
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
2. Install new Command line tools version
sudo xcode-select --install
3. after installing run below command
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```