# Unable to run gem command: match init

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I am trying to run a gem called match. https://codesigning.guide/

```
match init
```

When this runs the following is returned:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/match: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have seen other related posts but those do not resolve my issue: [CocoaPods not working in macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396215/cocoapods-not-working-in-macos-high-sierra/46484926)

It seems something somewhere is pointing toward Ruby 2.0, but that is not the current version in use.

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
```

rvm -v

```
rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

If I got to the path: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/ -- this has a folder 2.3 and Current.

I am not familiar with gems/ruby/rvm so unsure where to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `match` is installed system-wide on your computer (perhaps done previously, before you installed RVM). The shell is picking it up from `/usr/local/bin` instead of from your RVM installation.

Not sure why the path of RVM is not before `/usr/local/bin`, but a quick fix is to rename the file `match` in `/usr/local/bin` to something else, and then try again:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/match /usr/local/bin/match_old
hash -r
```

Now your shell should pick up `match` from your RVM installation instead (provided you've installed that gem under RVM).

Comment: thank you! I would have never worked that out. I did have to gem install match after as well.